# After by hiding its vertical header, can I let user resize the row of QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I know that the behaviour of [resizing row height](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode) for a `QTableWidget` was implemented in `QHeaderView`. But my case is I have to hide that annoying vertical header (you can't use alternate background color in it), but still let user resize row dynamically.

Is this even remotely possible? I am wondering whether user can resize row height by hovering on the bottom edge of a row...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified but my guess is you can grab mouse event on the row and determine if it is near top or bottom edge and interpret mouse move as a resize. If you can't grab on row basis you can surely for whole table and find which row it belongs to and determine edge to be moved and resize accordingly. In fact I would guess that once you figure out how to capture the event the code will be very similar to that used by the header. You might even be able to call that code from your event handler.

Comment: You have interesting idea there about capturing whether mouse close to the bottom edge of a row. Will try to test this. Anyway, although after subclassing vertical header I can made the color to alternate, but still it's very convenient for users to be able to size row by not going all the way to the left edge, to vertical header.